# get all variations of a string javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get all the variations of a certain string. This string will be broken up by dashes. And the letters can only vary within those dashes.

For instance, let's say I pass `DFI3-334-FG12` then I want to get all variations of that string for instance:

```
FI3-334-G12
FI3-334-F12
FI3-334-FG2
FI3-334-FG1
DI3-334-G12
DI3-334-F12
DI3-334-FG2
DI3-334-FG1
DF3-334-G12
DF3-334-F12
DF3-334-FG2
DF3-334-FG1
DFI-334-G12
DFI-334-F12
DFI-334-FG2
DFI-334-FG1
```

Can anyone assist with this? I have attempted loops but I only get as far as breaking it up and getting different parts of it:

```
FI3,DI3,DF3,DFI
334
G12,F12,FG2,FG1
```

This is my code:

```
        $('#filter').on('click',function() {
            var input = $('#code').val();
            var parts = input.split("-");
            var fixed = Array();
            for(var i=0;i<parts.length; i++) {
                if(parts[i].length != 3) {
                    k = 0;
                    fixed[i] = new Array();
                    for(var c=0;c<parts[i].length;c++) {
                        fixed[i][k] = parts[i].replace(parts[i].charAt(c),"");
                        k++;
                    }
                } else {
                    fixed[i] = parts[i];
                }
            }
            var final = Array();
            $.each(fixed,function(i) {
                $('#code_result').append(fixed[i] + "<br>");
            })
        });
```

Comment: I can't imagine why regex wouldn't easily solve this problem, possibly with the necessity of capture groups, however, without a more concise definition of variation, it's kind of difficult to provide a succinct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var string= 'DFI3-334-FG12';
    var parts = string.split('-');
    for(var i=0;i<parts[0].length;i++)
        for(var j=0;j<parts[2].length;j++){
            p1 = parts[0].substring(0,i)+parts[0].substring(i+1,parts[0].length);
            p2 = parts[2].substring(0,j)+parts[2].substring(j+1,parts[2].length);
            console.log(p1+'-'+parts[1]+'-'+p2);    
        }
```

Comment: This works for the example, but the string could also be `4DF-34D3-93F`. The 4 characters are not limited to the first and last 'section', so all 3 might be 4 characters long, or just 2, or just 1.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.you need to explain it well here in order to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many segments there are (3 in this case), you can use loops to get every possible combination.

See my example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/a6647m9e/1/

```
for(var i=0; i<parts[0].length; ++i) {
  for(var j=0; j<parts[1].length; ++j) {
      for(var k=0; k<parts[2].length; ++k) {
          strings.push(parts[0][i]+'-'+parts[1][j]+'-'+parts[2][k]);
      }
  }
}
```

And just so you know, you're looking at `(2^parts[0].length - 1) * (2^parts[1].length - 1) * (2^parts[2].length - 1)` combinations (1575 in this case), taking out the blank combinations.

**Note: this is all dependent on what your definition of "all possible combinations" is.**

Comment: I posted an example of what I want. This isn't even close.

Comment: If that's the case, then your example tells us only that you want SOME combinations but not others. It's up to you to tell us what you want. Don't just say "not even close".